# Fast, constant communication with background service

Tags: android, android-service

**Background:**
I have several apps that must connect to the same usb device on my android phone. In order to suppress constant permission requests and repeated unplug/plugs, I have built a background service to connect to the usb device. From there apps can communicate with the service.

**Problem:**
The apps need to pass every touch event to the usb device. All this traffic seems to create some delay (I have measured the delay for the passing the data on the order 10s and 100s of milliseconds). I use a bound service with a messenger/handler to pass the data right now.

Does anyone know of a faster service or a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you looking for something that will just work on your one device? Or is this something for wider distribution?

Comment: Right now I am just trying to put it on one phone. However, the goal is that it would be able to roll out to more devices (all procured and managed by my group) in the future. Are you looking at some sort of rooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your distribution scenario is constrained to your own firm, and not to the general public, you could go with a standard socket-based server approach. Rather than using a bound service and a `Messenger`, have your service open up a `ServerSocket` on a well-known port, and have the client apps connect to it.

It's conceivable that there's a way to use Unix-style domain sockets instead of TCP/IP sockets, but I'm not clear on whether that's possible through the Android SDK, only through the NDK, or not an option.

IOW, do it the same way you might on a desktop or a server.

Depending upon the nature of your device, you will still encounter delays, simply because the device is running M processes with N total threads on a CPU with C cores, and N usually is substantially greater than C. Context-switching between threads on the available cores takes time. This, of course, is substantially worse on single-core CPUs.

This approach would be scary for wide distribution, just for security reasons. Locking down the sockets to only be used by the desired apps would be your responsibility and may not be simple. But, if you are only going to use these devices in your own office, that's less of an issue.

Comment: Great suggestion, I have built it using sockets and appear to have cut the delay from a couple seconds down to a couple milliseconds. Like you mentioned, still some delay, but definitely an improvement. I might look into the domain sockets.